# Sending callback anonymous function vs existing function

Tags: javascript, function, callback, anonymous-function

I have this code snippet, where the callback only works when I define an anonymous function.

I wonder why sending `res.send()` function as a callback doesn't work? Shouldn't it work the same as the anonymous function? Like `.then()` should pass the argument to `res.send()` and call it.

What am I missing here?

```js
const create = (req, res) => {
    // This works.
    Driver.create(req.body).then((driver) => res.send(driver));

    // This doesn't work!
    Driver.create(req.body).then(res.send);
};
```

Comment: Because `send` is a **method**, it cares what `this` is when you call it. When you do `.then(res.send)`, it'll get called with `this` set to the default value (`undefined` in strict mode, the global object in loose mode). You can fix that with `bind`: `.then(res.send.bind(res))` but to me the arrow function is clearer.

Comment: (Note that none of this has anything to do with whether the callback is anonymous or not.)